# using python to use names from one sql table to find data in another and then combining the names and data to make an html table

Tags: python, html, sqlite, iteration

i have a list of unique names that i pulled from an sqlite database using the following code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
connection.text_factory = str
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute ('SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Description LIKE ?', [term])
my_object = []
for name in c:
    my_object.append(name)
return my_object
```

i want to use this list of unique names to look through another table in the same database and pull out four values. i.e. - 'SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4 FROM Table2 WHERE Name LIKE ***_*__**' where the blank would be each of the values in my list.  this is the part i really need help on

i then want to make an HTML table with the Name in the first column and all the corresponding values in the subsequent values (i know the HTML, but don't know how to lump all of this together using python).  if i could pull each value separately, i guess i could use zip to combine them and loop through the table, but i was hoping to do this in as few steps as possible.

i hope i'm being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could amend your SQL so that you pull out the names that are like a certain description, and then put out values from table2 for those matching names.

```sql
select name, value1, value2, value3, value4
from table2
where name in (
    select name
    from table1
    where description like ?
)
```

Comment: i did not know you could nest things in sql like that.  that worked, and definitely helped so far, but when i run the query in parentheses i get many matches and when i run it all together i just get the first match.  i would like it to return the name, value 1-4 for each of the names in the parenthetical list of results

Comment: @user1714887 The results you get, are where the name in table2 exists in the query from table1... I take it you're expecting a larger population? (Can you look at your data and check that is the case...) (take some of the names from the sub-query and look them up in table2 to confirm they exist/don't)

Comment: so it turns out i used LIKE instead of IN where you suggested.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1714887 no problem - surprised that using like returned anything :)